# How to run cql files (.cql) from within cqlsh?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0

The problem that I am having is that I want to run the following command (and I can't):

```
cqlsh < cql_directory/cql_create_stuff.cql
```

Because I have not logged in to cqlsh.

So I logged in:

```
cqlsh -u 'my_username' -p 'my_super_secret_password'
```

and now I tried doing the command in cqlsh shell but It just responds with a syntax error.

**Basically, how do I login into cqlsh and run an external CQL script in my file system?**

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use the `SOURCE`

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/source_r.html

You can use `-f` option as well to execute commands from file

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html

Comment: Yep that worked. Do you mind puttying an example explicitly too in your response? Thanks! :)

Comment: But its so annoying that I have to even go to the cqlsh, can't I login in bash and do it in bash and remain in bash? like cqlsh < cql_directory/cql_create_stuff.cql? The reason that worked before was because I did not have authentication set up, so u can only do that trick if authentication is set up?

Comment: ``bin/cqlsh -u user -p pwd -f file.cql`` should work

Comment: The original links on this answer were not working as of Oct 2019. The new link is https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh_commands/cqlshSource.html

Answer (score 34):

Assuming that the path of the file with the CQL commands is `/mydir/myfile.cql`, there are two ways:

If you are not logged in to cqlsh:

```
cqlsh -u 'my_username' -p 'my_password' -f /mydir/myfile.cql
```

If you are logged in to cqlsh:

```
SOURCE '/mydir/myfile.cql'
```

Notice the single quotation marks. The shorthand notation for `$HOME` (for example, `'~/mydir/myfile.cql'`) is also supported.

Both ways also work with relative paths (to the current directory).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your filename is "**tables.cql**" and it is placed as: `/files/tables.cql`;

#### A - Locally

```
cqlsh -f /files/tables.cql
```

#### B - Connecting To A Docker Container Running Cassandra

Assuming the name of the Docker container that which running **Cassandra** is "**cas**" (keep in mind that you can also use the hash id of the docker container if there is no name assigned to it);

```
docker exec -it cas cqlsh -f /files/tables.cql
```

As stated on other answers, `-u` and `-p` options can be added in order to use the username/password combinations.

Answer (score 0):

**This is for Window system**

suppose you cassandra dir is 
C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\bin

Suppose directory where your .cql file OR cql query file is 
D:\ril\s\developement\new one\excel after parse\Women catalogue template.cql

Now follow below steps for importing cql file

1. Go on command prompt (**cmd**)
2. Go on the directory where cql file is there (**cd "..\ril\sizeguide\developement\new one\excel after parse"**)
3. Run below command
   "c:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\bin\cqlsh.bat" <"Women catalogue template.cql"

And its Done.

Important Note:

- Please make sure column value should not have single quote **'** character like ('If you don't find a exact match, go for the next large size') other wise it will fail.
- If you want single quote to be inserted, please use it two times like below and Cassandra will treat it as one time
  ('If you don''t find a exact match, go for the next large size')
- All text column should be enclosed by single quote '' like 'Sale category'. For empty value, please use two single quote **''**.